# how do i update a gameobjects mesh collider to the new mesh filter

Tags: unity-game-engine, mesh-collider

so i made a few sword models and i want that when i change the sword mesh filter the mesh collider also updates altough i didnt understand how to refrence it.
here is my cuurent code for making it.
also if possible i would much prefer to use a box collider but i have zero idea how t oupdate a box collider when a mesh changes

```
;
[SerializeField] MeshFilter sword;
[SerializeField] MeshCollider swordcollider;
[SerializeField] Mesh[] mesh1;
 
private int currentmesh = 0;


public void changesword()
{
    
    sword.mesh = mesh1[currentmesh];
    swordcollider.mesh = mesh1[currentmesh];
    currentmesh++;
   
    if (currentmesh > mesh1.Length) { currentmesh = 0; }
    
}
```

also i do want to state that i have no idea what i am doing when it comes to meshes and mesh colliders which is why i didnt understand what to write. also the current mesh is a list of the sword meshes that way its way easier for me to switch. any help is apreciatted!